# CakePHP plugin throws "Missing View" error but view file exits

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I'm writing a basic plugin for my cakePHP 2.x app following the instructions in [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

I've created the directory/file structure with a MyPluginAppController.php and MyPluginAppModel.php.

I added `CakePlugin::load('MyPlugin');` to the parent app's bootstrap.php file.

Then I created one Controller and Model. But for some reason when I try to view `mysite.dev/(admin)/my_plugin/my_model/` I get a "Missing View" error. It says to confirm that the view file exists, which it does!

I don't think I skipped any steps from the book. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Controller path: `app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Controller/MyModelController.php`

View path: `app/Plugin/MyPlugin/View/MyModel/admin_index.php`

URL: `http://mysite.dev/admin/my_plugin/my_model/`

Comment: What is the path to the controller, and what is the path to the view file in your plugin? I have a hunch, but need more details first.

Comment: I updated the question with the requested info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename this file

```
app/Plugin/MyPlugin/View/MyModel/admin_index.php
```

To this extension `.ctp`

```
app/Plugin/MyPlugin/View/MyModel/admin_index.ctp
```

This is a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I was't using a plugin so my case was a bit different. However, this question shows up on the search results page, so I'll post this here.

This is the problematic controller.

```
<?php 

class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
    }

    public function view() {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

## The problem:

CakePHP kept showing me the following error:

> Missing View
>
> Error: The view for ArticlesController::view() was not found.
>
> Confirm you have created the file: Articles/view.ctp in one of the following paths:

## Debugging:

I checked all paths it suggested using [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) and the [`stat`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/linux_stat_command_with_examples12) command to make sure the view file exists and is indeed readable by PHP.

## Solution:

The issue there is the empty `beforeFilter()`. As soon as I removed it everything worked.