# Cakephp- missing view error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on creating a UI for a database using cakephp. I am very new to cakephp so I am a little stuck. I have successfully installed cakephp, connected it to the database. I have created the model, controller and view based on tutorials but when I try to load this page localhost/app this is the error I get
Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is the path to my controller: app/controller/OutagesController.php model: app/model/Outage.php view: app/View/Outages/index.ctp and my code is below
 Also, Am I loading the right URL?
Thanks in advance
Tayo6.

```
enter code here
Error message:
Missing View
ERROR: THE VIEW FOR APPCONTROLLER::INDEX() WAS NOT FOUND.
ERROR: CONFIRM YOU HAVE CREATED THE FILE:         /USERS/ESTHER.AGBAJI/SITES/CAKE/APP/VIEW/APP/INDEX.CTP
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create     app/View/Errors/missing_view.ctp
Stack Trace
    CORE/Cake/View/View.php line 468 → View->_getViewFileName(null)
    CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 948 → View->render(null, null)
    CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 194 → Controller->render()
    CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(AppController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
    APP/webroot/index.php line 110 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/index.php line 19 → require(string)


MODEL CLASS (Outage.php)
<?php


class Outage extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Outages';
}

var $validate = array(
'id' => array(
'rule' => 'notEmpty'),

'start_date' => array(
'rule'=>'date'
'allowEmpty' => true),

'end_date' => array(

'allowEmpty' => true),

'application' => array(

'allowEmpty' => true),

'environment' => array(

'allowEmpty' => true),

'business_impact' => array(
'allowEmpty' => true),

'notified_by' => array(
'allowEmpty' => true),

'details' => array(
'allowEmpty' => true),

'severity' => array(
'rule' => 'notEmpty'),

'state' => array(
'allowEmpty' => true),

'resolved' => array(
'rule' => 'notEmpty')

'jira' => array(

'allowEmpty' => true)

);

 ?>

CONTROLLER CLASS (OutagesController.php)

<?php

class OutagesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Outages';
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Ajax', 'Javascript');
   function index() {

    $this->set('outages', $this->Outage->find('all'));
    }
    function view($id = null) 
    {
    $this->Outage->id = $id;
    $this->set('outage', $this->Outage->read());
    print_r($this->viewVars);
    }
    $this->Outages->set($this->request->data);

}

?>
VIEW (index.ctp)

 <h2>Outages</h2>

<table>
    <tr>

        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>End date</th>
        <th>Application</th>
        <th>Environment</th>
        <th>Business impact</th>
        <th>Notified by</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Resolved</th>
        <th>Jira</th>

    </tr>

 <?php foreach ($outages as $outage: ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php> echo $outage['Outage']['id']?></td>

        <td>
        <?php> echo $html->link(($outage['Outage']['start_date'],
        array('controller'=> 'outages', 'action'=> 'view', $outage['Outage']['id']));?>
        </td>

        <td><?php echo $outage['Outage']['end_date']; ?></td>
</tr>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Thank you so much for your useful responses. I am now loading it the right way, using localhost/outages but I get this error message: Not Found The requested URL /outages was not found on this server. I have gone through my files and made sure they are in the right places. Tayo6

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful responses. I am now loading it the right way, using http://localhost/outages but I get this error message:
Not Found
The requested URL /outages was not found on this server.
 I have gone through my files and made sure they are in the right places.
 Tayo6

Comment: For those who came here from search. In my case `beforeFilter()` caused this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921021/cakephp-plugin-throws-missing-view-error-but-view-file-exits/40872968#40872968 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell exactly which URL from your description, but assuming you let localhost point directly to your webapplication, it should be `http://localhost/outages`

By using localhost/app you're trying to get the index of the 'AppController' (which exists, but is normally not used directly). To get a 'home' page for your app, your should use the PagesController.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be correct perhaps only problem is in the URL you are trying to access.

Try to access with the application root folder name which contains /app, /lib, /vendors etc.

For e.g. `http://localhost/testapp`

The first page to be run on browser, you can make that setting in `app/Config/routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'outages', 'action' => 'index'));
```