# "Missing View" error when trying to call Model method from Controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, templates, cakephp, cakephp-model

I am a CakePHP beginner and I think I must be missing some essential basic knowledge.  What I'm trying to do is to have a link in my View file that, when clicked, causes execution of a Model method.  I'm trying to use the CakePHP Blog Tutorial as a starting point.

My view file (Sites/view.ctp) includes the following links:

```
<tr><td class="label">Actions</td><td><?php echo $this->Form->postLink('Sync Pages', array('action' => 'sync', $site['Site']['id']), array('confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to try that?')); ?> | <?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $site['Site']['id'])); ?></td></tr>
```

My controller file (SitesController.php) includes the following functions:

```
// Delete function copied from the Cake tutorial    
public function delete($id) {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    if ($this->Site->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The site with id: %s has been deleted.', h($id)));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}

// My failing function (results in "Missing View" error)
public function sync($id) {     
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    if ($this->Site->syncPages($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The site with id: %s has been synced.', h($id)));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));
    }
}
```

And my model file (Site.php) includes the following draft of a function:

```
public function syncPages() {

    $cms = $this->cms;

    if ($this->cms == 'Wordpress')
    {
        // ... do stuff to retrieve data from a remote Wordpress database and save it to the local CakePHP app database
    }
}
```

But, as noted above, I can't get that syncPages() function to execute at all.  When I click on the Sync link, I get the "Missing View" error.  Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For those coming here from search: in my case `beforeFilter()` caused this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921021/cakephp-plugin-throws-missing-view-error-but-view-file-exits/40872968#40872968 for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add $this->layout = $this->autoRender = false to your sync function in the controller.

Comment: This is correct. I'd assume you (alison) need to know why it is correct though. CakePHP is a dumbed down framework that takes most of the work away from you. It expects that if you are working on a function named 'test' that a view named 'test.ctp' also exists. It doesn't care that you are redirecting - it still expects this file exist. Kai's code above tells the framework that you aren't going to be loading a layout and to not autoLoad the view like it does by default.

Comment: Thanks so much, Kai and skrilled! It seems that `$this->autoRender = false` alone does the trick to disable both layout and view (now I need to go read about what the difference is between the two... ;-)  I guess it must be the case that the autoRendering is turned off by default for the built-in "delete" functionality, right?