# CakePHP 2.5 missing view?

Tags: cakephp

Hi i've run in to a bit of a problem with my cake application - bassicaly the form which i implemented works fine its submitting into database, however when i give false credentials on purpose it asks for view in the Userscontroller, however i didnt create a view for the form action because my form is on my homepage can someone please help me out.
bless fred.

```
UsersController


  <?php

class UsersController extends AppController {

/*public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 25,
    'conditions' => array('status' => '1'),
    'order' => array('User.username' => 'asc' ) 
);
*/
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow();
}



public function login() {

    //if already logged-in, redirect
    if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));        
    }

    // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    } 
}

public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function index() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 6,
        'order' => array('User.username' => 'asc' )
    );
    $users = $this->paginate('User');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}


public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been created'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be created. Please, try again.'));
        }   
    }
}

public function edit($id = null) {

        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide a user id');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }

        $user = $this->User->findById($id);
        if (!$user) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid User ID Provided');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $this->User->id = $id;
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been updated'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $id));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your user.'));
            }
        }

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $user;
        }
}

public function delete($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide a user id');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid user id provided');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->User->saveField('status', 0)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}

/*public function activate($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Please provide a user id');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid user id provided');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->User->saveField('status', 1)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User re-activated'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not re-activated'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

*/
   }

?>

```
 home.ctp

 <div id="banner">

  <div id="mapbox">
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('map.png', array('alt' => 'logo', 'width' => "300", 'height' =>     "253")); ?>

</div><!--mapbox ends<!---->

  <p>What's your problem?</p>
  <ul>
      <li><?php echo $this-> html->link('Share Problem', array('action' =>    'problem'),array('class'=>'share_prob'));?></li>
</ul>
</div><!--banner ends-->
<div id="leftcol">
<p class="darkgry bold spacer">Browse problems by</p>
<ul class="browsprob">
<li><a class="locbtn" href="#">Location</a></li>
<li><a class="urgbtn" href="#">Urgency</a></li>
<li><a class="rewbtn" href="#">Reward</a></li>
<li><a class="chabtn" href="#">Charity</a></li>
<li><a class="relbtn" href="#">Reliability</a></li>
</ul>
  <div id="innerleft">
  <p class="title">Sign Up</p>
   <p class="title2">Already have an account? <?php echo $this-> html->link('Login', array('action'    => 'login'));?>
<div id="facebook">
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('facebook.png', array('alt' => 'facebook logo')); ?>

   </div>
   <div id="linked">
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('linked.png', array('alt' => 'linked logo')); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="register">


    <div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'add'));?>

       <div class="firstname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('class' => 'input01'));?>
        </div>


    <div class="lastname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('class' =>'input02'));?>
    </div>
    <div class = "firstname">

        <?php echo $this->Form->input('location', array('class' => 'input03'));?>
    </div>
    <div class="firstname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('class' =>'input03'));?>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'input03'));?>
    </div>

    <div class="lastname">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('class' => 'input02'));?>
    </div>

        <div class="email">
       <?php   echo $this->Form->input('password_confirm', array('label' => 'Confirm Password *', 'maxLength' => 255, 'title' => 'Confirm password', 'type'=>'password', 'class' =>'input03'));?>
    </div>




    <?php echo  $this->Form->submit('Register', array('class' => 'inputbutton'));?>
    <?php   $this->Form->end()?>



        <p class="tick">I agree to your T&C's <input class="box" type="checkbox" name="sports" value="soccer"  /><br />

     </div>


</div>


 </div><!--leftcol ends-->


<div id="rightcol">

<div id="innerright">
<h3>TOP SOLVERS</h3>

<ul id="topsolv">
    <li>
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('top_solv.png', array('alt' => 'profile pic', 'width' =>   "121", 'height' => "121")); ?>
        </li>
        <li>
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('top_solv.png', array('alt' => 'profile pic', 'width' => "121", 'height' => "121")); ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('top_solv.png', array('alt' => 'profile pic', 'width' => "121", 'height' => "121")); ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('top_solv.png', array('alt' => 'profile pic', 'width' => "121", 'height' => "121")); ?>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <h3>Recently Solved</h3>
    <ul id="solvedprob">
    <li>
           <?php echo $this->Html->image('prof_img.jpg', array('alt' => 'profile image', 'width' => "51", 'height' => "52")); ?>
           <p class="bold">Problem</p>
           <p class="bluebold">From User <span class="highlight">New User</span></p>
           <p class="darkgry small">Posted on 01/01/13 at 00:00</p>
         </li>
        <li>
              <?php echo $this->Html->image('prof_img.jpg', array('alt' => 'profile image', 'width' => "51", 'height' => "52")); ?>
           <p class="bold">Problem</p>
            <p class="bluebold">From User <span class="highlight">New User</span></p>
            <p class="darkgry small">Posted on 01/01/13 at 00:00</p>
         </li>
         <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->image('prof_img.jpg', array('alt' => 'profile image', 'width' => "51", 'height' => "52")); ?>
             <p class="bold">Problem</p>
             <p class="bluebold">From User <span class="highlight">New User</span></p>
        <p class="darkgry small">Posted on 01/01/13 at 00:00</p>
         </li>
        <li>
              <?php echo $this->Html->image('prof_img.jpg', array('alt' => 'profile image', 'width' => "51", 'height' => "52")); ?>
           <p class="bold">Problem</p>
           <p class="bluebold">From User <span class="highlight">New User</span></p>
           <p class="darkgry small">Posted on 01/01/13 at 00:00</p>
          </li>
        <li>
               <?php echo $this->Html->image('prof_img.jpg', array('alt' => 'profile image', 'width' => "51", 'height' => "52")); ?>
           <p class="bold">Problem</p>
           <p class="bluebold">From User <span class="highlight">New User</span></p>
          <p class="darkgry small">Posted on 01/01/13 at 00:00</p>
       </li>
        <li>
           <?php echo $this->Html->image('prof_img.jpg', array('alt' => 'profile image', 'width' => "51", 'height' => "52")); ?>
            <p class="bold">Problem</p>
            <p class="bluebold">From User <span class="highlight">New User</span></p>
           <p class="darkgry small">Posted on 01/01/13 at 00:00</p>
            </li>
         <p class="darkgry bold alignright">VIEW MORE
           <?php echo $this->Html->image('more.gif', array('alt' => 'arrows', 'width' => "15", 'height' => "17")); ?>
    </ul>

 </div><!--innerright ends-->
 </div><!--rightcol ends-->
```

Comment: For those who came here from search: in my case `beforeFilter()` caused this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921021/cakephp-plugin-throws-missing-view-error-but-view-file-exits/40872968#40872968 for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a mess to look at, you should have left only what is needed for the problem and not just everything in there (like commented parts, css, images and what not).

What I figure is that you don't understand the flow of your code. From you homepage you post a form to `/users/add` and so when it fails you end up there where a view is missing. If it succeeds you have a redirect to `index` (in `Users`) for which I suppose a view exists.

Also take a look at your `UsersController::beforeFilter()` you have a `$this->Auth->allow();` which means all actions in that controller are allowed for non authenticated users. That means anyone can change anyones password or delete all your users.

Comment: cheers for that mate i managed to figure it out, just one little thing though for some reason, the flash error messages is not displaying from controller and model what do u think it could be?    PS: sorry about messy code :)

Comment: If an answer helped solve your problem please mark it as accepted. If you did something different to solve it, post that as an answer and mark it. Comments aren't for asking something new. Flash messages shouldn't ever be generated from models, they don't belong there in the MVC paradigm. As to why they are not displayed, there can be multiple reasons so research and if you can't find an answer please post a new question with relevant info.